# (python, Kivy) Как перерисовать canvas во время выполнения программы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, desktop

Пишу программу, которая в зависимости от соотношения дву переменных **pulse_length** и
**distance_length**, меняет координаты двух точек [этой](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GrKZ2TZjfjj4M2C1XO0vuUVo09zidC7hq3SywNWciYHkpQ8wq1xIw6mELrt990WUaJUnxheK3K4ljKM9AUWzN1mBhbSUcdn_rr_aTTN1-NJPIbrMSz2-qZOjME-BU6mE_XwXegONSGiU1f-Q0XQ-1mSgk5SRlRx82RM0nUFjTXhzFQBn2CcOUMftYGbhP2KWIP32nb7vEHWXuKY61iw5O7xW9NdCDZXysLYq4dUeH01LTlN-SgFYc5eqyLP1IpIaLG1SvtsDE-SFZcMAhE6a8Cx9GSBBeNVpXn61i7rw3lpjWuzGKnilqCSL1LsqHJqvhY_UyzXwrRjymVLMdaFxwhplg2C4XyeXs_2-TLDi_r7HWPgzAhFPhFnsVMwBitf8b3t0wVby1Cuoqw7MSIVLOIDwsnNr9T4lZtLk6mfuFri4QRx1WBsggDiONg1_J9GO3W2Q3jHJqsWFBVEZai6vWGr0lEJY66p6WRkWJPbn5VQ2L5v8kuwhA75ukydo5duZkcITIfD8gE9RG0Qgul0h1lWfK15vibQd48IwSg7DH7P0-VSY4WlXShHwXjweso0Ebki6JCYLFG1ixYm3Nfy9RXDi5JxpBlC0DAlYZPegCcT8A_ZqkVVEhHvgdlSY9TeHWQZSjoQjremQaiiRJLr25hXC1XU60Q=w621-h287-no) линий. Значение этих переменных задает пользователь через TextInput

Пытаюсь реализовать это так: 
высчитываю соотношение ratio = (distance_length / (distance_length + pulse_length). Создаю виджет TextInput. При выполнении события **on_text_validate** перезаписываю переменные **pulse_length** и
**distance_length**, и перерисовываю **Line.canvas** с помощью **Line.canvas.ask_update()**. Проблема в том что Line.canvas.ask_update() работает, видимо, не так как я предпологал.

Вот упрощенный код программы:

```py
# input variables
pulse_length = 499
distance_length = 999

# calculations
ratio = (distance_length / (distance_length + pulse_length) * 540) + 40

class Line(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Line, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            kg.Line(
                points=(
                    20, 350,
                    40, 350,
                    40, 240,
                    ratio, 240,
                    ratio, 350,
                    560, 350,
                    560, 240,
                    620, 240),

            # Other instructions ...

            Callback(self.update)
    def update(self, inst):
        ratio = (distance_length / (distance_length + pulse_length) * 540) + 40
        self.canvas.ask_update()

class TextInputGrid(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TextInputGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.inputlayout = GridLayout(cols=1, size=(100, 30))
        self.inputlayout.textfield = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inputlayout.add_widget(self.inputlayout.textfield)

class MyFloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # Drawn line widget
        self.add_widget(Line())

        # TextInput 1
        self.textinput1 = TextInputGrid()
        self.textinput1.inputlayout.textfield.bind(on_text_validate=self.enter_pulse)

        # TextInput 2
        self.textinput2 = TextInputGrid()
        self.textinput2.inputlayout.textfield.bind(on_text_validate=self.enter_distance)

        self.add_widget(self.textinput1.inputlayout)
        self.add_widget(self.textinput2.inputlayout)

    def enter_pulse(self, instance):
        global pulse_length
        pulse_length = int(self.textinput1.inputlayout.textfield.text)

    def enter_distance(self, instance):
        global distance_length
        distance_length = int(self.textinput2.inputlayout.textfield.text)


class GeneratorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyFloatLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GeneratorApp().run()
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правельно реализовать такую программу. Правельно ли я понимаю, то как должен работать ask_update()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так и не понял как работает ask_update(). Решение подсказали английском stackoverflow: удалять и рисовать новый canvas обьект. Вот более менее рабочий код

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import kivy.graphics as kg

# input variables
pulse_length = 499
distance_length = 999

class Line(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ratio = (distance_length / (distance_length + pulse_length) * 540) + 40
        super(Line, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            self.line = kg.Line(
                points=(
                    20, 350,
                    40, 350,
                    40, 240,
                    ratio, 240,
                    ratio, 350,
                    560, 350,
                    560, 240,
                    620, 240))

            # Other instructions ...

            #Callback(self.update)
    def update(self):
        ratio = (distance_length / (distance_length + pulse_length) * 540) + 40
        self.canvas.remove(self.line)
        with self.canvas:
            self.line = kg.Line(
                points=(
                    20, 350,
                    40, 350,
                    40, 240,
                    ratio, 240,
                    ratio, 350,
                    560, 350,
                    560, 240,
                    620, 240))

class TextInputGrid(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TextInputGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.inputlayout = GridLayout(cols=1, size=(100, 30))
        self.inputlayout.textfield = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inputlayout.add_widget(self.inputlayout.textfield)

class MyFloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # Drawn line widget
        self.line = Line()
        self.add_widget(self.line)

        # TextInput 1
        self.textinput1 = TextInputGrid(pos=(0,0))
        self.textinput1.inputlayout.textfield.bind(on_text_validate=self.enter_pulse)

        # TextInput 2
        self.textinput2 = TextInputGrid(pos=(100,100))
        self.textinput2.inputlayout.textfield.bind(on_text_validate=self.enter_distance)

        self.add_widget(self.textinput1.inputlayout)
        self.add_widget(self.textinput2.inputlayout)

    def enter_pulse(self, instance):
        global pulse_length
        pulse_length = int(self.textinput1.inputlayout.textfield.text)
        self.line.update()

    def enter_distance(self, instance):
        global distance_length
        distance_length = int(self.textinput2.inputlayout.textfield.text)
        self.line.update()


class GeneratorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyFloatLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GeneratorApp().run()
```